# programmatic segue from view

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am trying to seg onto a screen on tap of a view. I have the following code:

```
func addSegEvents(){
        let currentWeekTapper = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action:Selector("segToCurRoster"))
        currentWeekTapper.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.currentWeekView?.addGestureRecognizer(currentWeekTapper)

    }

func segToCurRoster(){
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("landingToCurRoster", sender: self)
}
```

I am calling addSegEvents in my viewDidLoad. I am getting the error unrecognized selector sent to instance. This is usually due to a missing/extra colon but that is not the case here so I don't know what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target must be self because the `segToCurRoster()` is declared in self not view:

```
let currentWeekTapper = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("segToCurRoster"))
```